# Swagger CodeGen Dependency Issues

Tags: maven, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to get a project up and running with [Swagger codegen Maven plugin](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/modules/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin). I have the following `plugin` in my `pom.xml`.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-rc1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                        <language>spring</language>
                        <configOptions>
                            <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run `mvn clean compile`, I get a bunch of dependency errors. For example, `fasterxml` and `threeten`. I'm surprised that the dependencies wouldn't be automatically configured and that everything would work out of the box. Am I doing something wrong or do you really need to manually add the dependencies to `pom.xml`?

**UPDATE**

While digging through the code, I noticed there is a generated `pom.xml` (`target/generated-sources/swagger` with my config above) that seems to have the dependencies I need. Googling led to an [issue thread](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/5410) concerning my problem. Looks like this is potentially a known issue.

The dependency copying worked when I used `<language>jaxrs-resteasy</language>` but I'm still working on other use cases (the `spring` I originally had and also `jaxrs-jersey`).